# Linux DLNA Server

Tags: linux, video, streaming, media-server, dlna

I have just [recently](http://blog.kaleb.hornsby.ws/2010/03/streaming-media-from-linux-to-ps3-with.html) set up a DLNA server on my GNU/Linux desktop at home. I am using PS3 Media Server to do the job. I like it a lot so far, but I was curious about whether or not it is the best solution. To you, what is the best DLNA server for Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found Mediatomb to work with very little configuration. I now have replaced it with a Netgear ReadyNAS box. It is a bit pricey, but also very elegent. Iirc it is running a custom DLNA server, easily configurable through the FrontView web ui.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I use [mediatomb](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128231720/http://mediatomb.cc/) ([SourceForge project page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mediatomb/)) and find it to work flawlessly, although it sure took some configuring.

It runs as a system service (started from `/etc/init.d` on boot) and I've set it to auto-update indexes so I never need to touch it now.

I also set up a little IMDB lookup script that moves movies into directories based on their IMDB rating.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20181124081742/http://www.rbgrn.net/content/21-how-to-choose-dlna-media-server-windows-mac-os-x-or-linux) gives a pretty good breakdown of a lot of choices.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I had already came across that one from Google. I was curious about what SuperUser members' thoughts were. Not to mention, its just information and not too much commentary about preference. The article is also from 2007.

Comment: please delete your post or update the link with one that works as the original link is dead. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use mediatomb. See [this post](http://www.dbstalk.com/showthread.php?t=128910) for a bunch of great uses.