# Is it possible to push multimedia content on DLNA TV from Linux?

Tags: linux, streaming, dlna

On Windows I loved the "Play To" function included in Windows Media Player to push content to my Samsung TV.
But now that I am on Linux I don't know how to do the same thing. I found how to setup a DLNA server and retrieve it's content from the TV but this is not what I'm really looking for..

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, check out [servioo](http://www.serviio.org/) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/117033/linux-dlna-server) superuser question.

Comment: Not a real answer... Expand the links in case they go dead (at least summarize).

Comment: @studiohack It's to an SU question and an software page, not instructions

Comment: @HackToHell SU pages can be deleted... I was suggesting that you paste (with credit) or summarize *proof* of it being possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Kinsky](http://oss.linn.co.uk/trac/wiki/Kinsky) by Linn can do this across all platforms.  It is in effect a uPnP control point.

For Android there is [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp).  This is capable of serving all DLNA/UPnP purposes outlined below, and is an excellent tool for carrying out tests.

On linux there is the gupnp-av-cp app that is part of [gupnp-tools](https://wiki.gnome.org/GUPnP/).  I have read that it's also possible to to use pulseaudio (with rygel?) to push all system sound to a UPnP/DLNA device and am in the process investigating/implementing this.  Will update when I know more.

On OSX 10.8, iTunes is capable of sending to both AirPlay and UPnP/DLNA devices.

To put this in perspective, DLNA, also referred to as uPnP, has three important devices:

1. Media servers
2. Media renderer
3. Media control point

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [pulseaudio-dlna](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna) package.

Comment: link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken

Answer (score 1):

DLNA renderer: Pure Jonga A240

For audio only,the pulseaudio-dlna package does the job on Ubuntu 19.04 despite some errors during install. There is a 12 second lag (on my setup) and some stuttering during volume adjustment. But simply amazing functionality and simplicity. It's the only I've way I've found to push internet audio to a dlna renderer via linux. There are a huge number of options for Android and an almost complete dearth of them for linux.

For pushing local video/audio content, it's a lot easier: install the Emby server (google for instructions), then hook up to the web-based interface of the server via a browser (on the linux PC itself or a browser on another device). The web interface gives you a media player complete with a "Play To.." option where your dlna renderer is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have installed Emby Server on Ubuntu 18.04 for streaming local music content to DLNA Compilant TV and it works like a Charm. All of my content is stored on Synology drive which is mounted on my linux server and i can stream my entire playlist to my TV connected to yamaha music amplifier. Superb job by Emby team.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the people that seem to be excited here are talking about streaming media, but question was to stream Linux video output (screen) to a renderer like you can do on the other devices. This is also called casting, and for video it is missing, so making a screen on TV still requires a long cable it seems. Most devices are just receivers.